# ExtJS 4 & C# REST - Basic example

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, extjs4, asp.net-3.5

I'm building a simple .NET 3.5 Web Application that uses ExtJS 4

I've created ASP.NET Application, added ExtJS to it and did all client-server communication with asmx services.
But I would like to convert them into REST services.
I was looking over the net but didn't found any example.

I have tried to add svc service to my solution, but I don't know which one should I use? Ajax-enabled or WCF Service.

I need only 4 simple operations (for now) in my service:

- Get all records,
- Create new record
- Update record
- Delete record

Standard CRUD, but I would like to create it using REST.

1. How to create a REST service inside ASP.NET Web Application.
2. How should I name my methods and how to create uri templates for them so
   they will work with ExtJS?
3. How to configure Web.config so that it all will work.

I found this question: [REST from asp.net 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691111/rest-from-asp-net-2-0)
but I would like to know how to connect REST with ExtJS.

**My questions:
How should I add WCF Service (svc) to ASP.NET Application (VS2005, .NET 3.5),
 how to create methods and configure Web.config to allow communication between ExtJS rest store and webservice.**

Comment: Have you thought of using ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but my application is very simple - just one asp page that hosts ExtJS application. All the logic is done by Ext and on server side I have right now asmx services (SOAP if I'm right) and I would like to change those to REST using WCF. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with .Net 3.5

Comment: Well, you can use an Ajax enabled WCF service but, thats not important, you can use whatever you want to be your end point, the important question here is how to map REST actions to it, with Asp.Net MVC you can do it pretty simple but, otherwise you have to create a simple handler to map your REST routes and map it in web.config its not complicated either but its a bit more work.

Comment: @VoidMain - thanks for help, I'm rightn now moving my services to Asp.Net MVC4 and trying to use WebAPI, with it doing REST should be easy :)

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide) is a nice WCF-REST tutorial